# Why won't OpenSSL link properly on Windows

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.0d for a Managed C++ project built with Visual Studio 2013. Building for Debug works great, but building for Release generates these linker errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv23_server_method
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLv23_client_method
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_num_locks
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_cleanup
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_load_error_strings
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_library_init
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_free_strings
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CONF_modules_free
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sk_num
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sk_value
```

I've tried using my own build of OpenSSL as well as a pre-compiled version from sigmoid, and results are the same.

My hypothesis is that while these OpenSSL builds are with '/MD', that alone isn't enough to be compatible with my Managed C++ project.  Since there are no direct calls from the Managed layer into OpenSLL, however, my understanding is that building with '/MD' should suffice. Plus, the Debug version works just fine. So why does just the Release one choke?

What is causing these linker errors, and how do I resolve them?

Comment: What are you trying to link with OpenSSL? Your own OpenSSL code or some other library?

Comment: Poco C++ libraries.  I have my own VS project for Poco that builds with CLR support turned on -- even though no C# code calls Poco code direcly either.  I have a wrapper layer of C++ code that encapsulates the few calls I make.  This code has been working for 2+ years with prior versions of OpenSSL and Poco, I'm just trying to update them both to relatively-current versions.

Comment: Please state the location of the Release build of OpenSSL. Please show the output of the link command. The build results are saved in a HTML file in the intermediate folder, IIRC.

Comment: I have the build logs, but they're massive. Can I pull something specific from them for you?  Not sure I still have any intermediate files laying around. The release build libraries are in "bin/lib", not "bin/lib64".  Plus as mentioned I tried using a third-party build and got the same results.

Comment: I believe we only need the two items: (1) state the location of the Release build of OpenSSL; and (2) show the link command and its output.

Comment: I no longer have the build directories, didn't think I'd need them.  So let's eliminate that variable and just use the binaries from sigmoid, which come from their 'lib' directory.  Exact same link errors occur.  What next?

Comment: I rebuilt again from scratch and again the .libs are in the 'lib' directory of the final result/install folder.  I cannot identify where the build placed intermediate files during the 'nmake' execution.  Same results as the original, indicating some kind of mismatch in the RTL linkage.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using the wrong OpenSSL version. Try OpenSSL v1.0.2k. The symbols it is complaining about are not included in the 1.1.x branch.

Remember to also link in ws_lib32.lib and crypt32.lib if necessary.

Comment: I rebuilt using a slightly newer version of 1.1.x and it worked. Never found out what the issue was with the old version, but I was trying to use that version to be 100% compatible with the server side. Having a slightly different version didn't break anything there either, so moving forward...

Comment: From the changelog of POCO C++ (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pocoproject/poco/poco-1.7.8p2-release/CHANGELOG) it seems they fixed the library to compile against OpenSSL v.1.1.x on POCO C++ v1.7.7, maybe you were initially using an older version or something.

Comment: In my case, one of the linked library was previously built using different version of OpenSSL. Rebuilding that lib solved the issue (as suggested in this answer).